# Rails/Refinery CMS: Adding to existing application + modifying existing code via CMS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, content-management-system, refinerycms

I've been reading the documentation on Refinery CMS but I haven't seemed to come across the right answer yet. If you have an existing Ruby on Rails application, is there a way to add Refinery to it and then run a command so that your previous models become refinery compatible, that is, you design a page and then it becomes editable in the refinery editors?

I'm asking because I'm planning on designing a website for a non-profit that does not have the resources for paid web developers. Is it possible for one web developer to write out the code and then have it all be editable by the editor? Does anyone have any experience with this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you have an existing Ruby on Rails application

You can add Refinery CMS in an existing Rails application:
http://www.refinerycms.com/guides/with-an-existing-rails-app

> run a command so that your previous models become refinery compatible, that is, you design a page and then it becomes editable in the refinery editors

No, you will have to manually convert this models.

> I'm asking because I'm planning on designing a website for a non-profit that does not have the resources for paid web developers. Is it possible for one web developer to write out the code and then have it all be editable by the editor? Does anyone have any experience with this? Thank you in advance.

Why don't you use a static website generator like middleman or Jekyll ? And choose a Headless/Decoupled CMS like Contentful.

Refinery CMS will soon be able to use it like a Headless CMS but it needs more work to do that:

- https://github.com/refinerycms-contrib/refinerycms-api
- https://github.com/refinerycms-contrib/refinerycms-api-wrapper
- https://github.com/refinerycms-contrib/refinerycms_middleman